# PasswordField in Django model?

Tags: django

I am trying to create a simple model called Username like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100) #Id is automatically generated by Django
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

This is the Django model that I am trying to create. The problem is username and password attribute is stored as CharField whereas I want password to be stored as **** or encrypted form in the database.It seems like they don't have PasswordField like CharField in Django. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to display the entered password in the form as * or do you want to insert it to db like that? BEcause for the former one, you need to use django forms, and add widget to CharField(look [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/PasswordField)), for the latter one, there is not anything like that, you just get the password, encrypt it and insert it to db..

Comment: Please don't try and create your own authentication. You will get it wrong. Use Django's built-in auth library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per [THE DOCS](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/PasswordField) it's

```
password = forms.CharField( 
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False), 
    label="Your Password"
)
```

and this lends to a

```
<input type="password" />
```

in your rendered form

About your storing part, you will need to store an hash of the password, not a list of * or you won't be able to retrieve it anyway. You could use the [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) module

```
user.password = hashlib.sha224(user.password).hexdigest()
user.save()
```

of course you have to pay big attention when implementing this. This above is just a quick example, check the docs for further learning

Comment: I want to insert in Database too.

Answer (score 0):

Django comes with User model. It's under django.contrib.auth.models. The model has everything you need and it's would be silly to start creating your own if there is one already. You also have a user creating and authentication forms in django.contrib.auth.forms, things like set_password method in user model and heaps more stuff.

Comment: I want to use another table from another database.